# Why can't I see my texture in material preview in weight paint mode?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have been following a course in Udemy, and in the course, I am supposed to be weight painting so that the displacement layer is only over the bricks. But in material preview mode when I go into weight paint mode I can't see my material like the video instructor can. The sphere also turns pink when I go into object mode, but I'm not sure if that's related at all. I have tried reading several articles and looking through other questions people have asked, but I still can't see my texture on the sphere in weight paint mode in the material preview.

I am using blender version 2.83
How can I still see the textures while in weight paint mode in the material preview?

Answer (score 1):

In 3.0 (basically, since 2.80) Blender has had an "overlays" menu which allows you to control how a lot of things-- like weight paint overlays-- are shown:

[image]

Here, while in a material preview, I've decreased the weight paint opacity slider, allowing my green material to show through the (blue) weight paint overlay.  If I decreased that all the way to 0.0, I would only see my material.

The exact options shown in the overlay dropdown are context specific.  For example, it won't show you weight paint overlay as an option unless you are in weight paint mode.

I can't be sure that this was the exact method used by your Udemy instructor, not without seeing them work, but this is *a* way to show your material while in weight paint mode.